# What Type should the dense vector be, when using UDF function in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to change List to Vector in pySpark, and then use this column to Machine Learning model for training. But my spark version is 1.6.0, which does not have `VectorUDT()`. So what type should I return in my udf function?

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.types import *


conf = SparkConf().setAppName('rank_test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SQLContext(sc)


df = spark.createDataFrame([[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]]],['a'])
print '???'
df.show()
def list2vec(column):
    print '?????',column
    return Vectors.dense(column)
getVector = udf(lambda y: list2vec(y),DenseVector() )
df.withColumn('b',getVector(col('a'))).show()
```

I have tried many Types , and this `DenseVector()` give me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 21, in <module>
    getVector = udf(lambda y: list2vec(y),DenseVector() )
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use vectors and VectorUDT with UDF,

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

ud_f = F.udf(lambda r : Vectors.dense(r),VectorUDT())
df = df.withColumn('b',ud_f('a'))
df.show()
+-------------------------+---------------------+
|a                        |b                    |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
|[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]|[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]|
+-------------------------+---------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
  |-- a: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
  |-- b: vector (nullable = true)
```

About VectorUDT, http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/linalg.html

Comment: Thank you, but my spark version is 1.6.0, which does not have VectorUDT, this's why I asked this question

Comment: 1.6 has VectorUDT in mllib. Just import as , from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT, http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/linalg.html

Comment: You are right, thank u

Comment: what is the equivalent in scala (ud_f = F.udf(lambda r : Vectors.dense(r),VectorUDT())) ?