# Convert libsvm format string ("field1:value field2:value") to DenseVector of the values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a column in libsvm format (ml library of spark) `field1:value field2:value ...`

```
+--------------+-----+
|      features|label|
+--------------+-----+
|   a:1 b:2 c:3|    0|
|   a:4 b:5 c:6|    0|
|   a:7 b:8 c:9|    1|
|a:10 b:11 c:12|    0|
+--------------+-----+
```

I want to extract the values and save them in arrays for each row in pyspark

```
features.printSchema()

root
 |-- features: string (nullable = false)
 |-- label: integer (nullable = true)
```

I am using the following udf because the column affected is part of a dataframe

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

features_expl = udf(lambda features: Vectors.dense(features.split(" ")).map(lambda feat: float(str(feat.split(":")[1]))))
features=features.withColumn("feats", features_expl(features.features))
```

The result I get is:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: mobile:0.0
It seems that it doesn't perform the second split and calls float() on a string.

What i would like to get is:

```
+--------------+-----+
|      features|label|
+--------------+-----+
|     [1, 2, 3]|    0|
|     [4, 5, 6]|    0|
|     [7, 8, 9]|    1|
|  [10, 11, 12]|    0|
+--------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems with your `udf`. Firstly, it doesn't work as you intended. Consider the heart of your code as the following function:

```python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
def features_expl_non_udf(features): 
    return Vectors.dense(
        features.split(" ")).map(lambda feat: float(str(feat.split(":")[1]))
    )
```

If you call it on one of your strings:

```python
features_expl_non_udf("a:1 b:2 c:3")
#ValueError: could not convert string to float: a:1
```

Because `features.split(" ")` returns `['a:1', 'b:2', 'c:3']`, which you are passing to the `Vectors.dense` constructor. This does not make any sense.

What you intended to do was first split on space, then split each value of the resultant list on `:`. Then you can convert these values to `float` and pass the list to `Vectors.dense`.

Here is the proper implementation of your logic:

```python
def features_expl_non_udf(features): 
    return Vectors.dense(map(lambda feat: float(feat.split(":")[1]), features.split()))
features_expl_non_udf("a:1 b:2 c:3")
#DenseVector([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

Now the second problem with your `udf` is that you didn't specify a `returnType`. For a `DenseVector` you need to [use `VectorUDT` as the `returnType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623620/what-type-should-the-dense-vector-be-when-using-udf-function-in-pyspark).

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT

features_expl = udf(
    lambda features: Vectors.dense(
        map(lambda feat: float(feat.split(":")[1]), features.split())
    ),
    VectorUDT()
)
features.withColumn("feats", features_expl(features.features)).show()
#+--------------+-----+----------------+
#|      features|label|           feats|
#+--------------+-----+----------------+
#|   a:1 b:2 c:3|    0|   [1.0,2.0,3.0]|
#|   a:4 b:5 c:6|    0|   [4.0,5.0,6.0]|
#|   a:7 b:8 c:9|    1|   [7.0,8.0,9.0]|
#|a:10 b:11 c:12|    0|[10.0,11.0,12.0]|
#+--------------+-----+----------------+
```

---

As an alternative, you can do the string processing part on the spark side using [`regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) and [`split`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) but you'll still have to use a `udf` to convert the final output to a `DenseVector`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, split, udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT

toDenseVector = udf(Vectors.dense, VectorUDT())

features.withColumn(
    "features",
    toDenseVector(
        split(regexp_replace("features", r"\w+:", ""), "\s+").cast("array<float>")
    )
).show()
#+----------------+-----+
#|        features|label|
#+----------------+-----+
#|   [1.0,2.0,3.0]|    0|
#|   [4.0,5.0,6.0]|    0|
#|   [7.0,8.0,9.0]|    1|
#|[10.0,11.0,12.0]|    0|
#+----------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So return type is only needed for UDF? Because you don't have it in the def code...

Comment: @GeorgiosKourogiorgas yes the `def` is a pure python function. For `udf`s that will be used in spark, you need a `returnType`. If you don't specify, it will default to `StringType`

Comment: What is the original features contains `None` value, such as `['"b":2','"a":1 "b":2 "c":3']`